# How to change Angular time picker to HH:MM:SS?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
  <div class="ngx-timepicker-field-example">
          <ngx-timepicker-field [controlOnly]="true"></ngx-timepicker-field>
      </div>
```

[image]

- I want to change this one to **HH:MM:SS**. So **"AM"** want to remove! How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Remove you will need to convert it into 24-hour format. You can do this with

```
<div class="ngx-timepicker-field-example">
   <ngx-timepicker-field [controlOnly]="true" [format]=24></ngx-timepicker-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's removed but i want to add SS to that removed place!

Comment: @Kevin_Mac I don't believe it is possible with the component you are using. If you want to use seconds you may want to use another component. Here is one [link](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/timepicker)

Comment: Thank you . I think I have to use another component !